# Objective-C issue with connectionDidFinishLoading and Delegate

Tags: objective-c, api, delegates

Am trying to use an API class to fetch data from a URL and then have that data returned to a method inside the ViewController. I have the ViewController call the API method.

Have tried several places on SO already and come up with the following, but it is not working and as an Objective-C noobie have tried reading documentation and such but still not understanding what could be going wrong.

I have a viewcontroller calling an method 'fetch' inside a class 'api'.
I have the connection delegates inside api class and it works ok (correct data is printed inside `connectionDidFinishLoading` method).
I need a delegate to return the data to a method inside the viewcontroller class.

So far I have

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "Api.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <apiDelegate>{

}

- (void)apiSucceeded:(NSString *)jsonString;
- (void)apiFailed:(NSString *)failedMessage;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Api.h"

- (void)apiSucceeded:(NSString *)jsonString {
    NSLog(@"WORKED");
}
- (void)apiFailed:(NSString *)failedMessage {
    NSLog(@"FAILED");
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Api* myapi = [[Api alloc]init]; 
    [myapi fetch]; 
}
@end
```

**Api.h**

```
@protocol apiDelegate
@required
- (void)apiSucceeded:(NSString *)jsonString;
- (void)apiFailed:(NSString *)failedMessage;
@end


@interface Api : NSObject {
    id _delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id _delegate;

-(void)fetch;
@end
```

**Api.m**

```
#import "Api.h"
#import "ViewController.h" 

@synthesize _delegate; 

- (void)fetch{  

//connection setup....
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.receivedData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //  NSLog(@"append data");
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
    // NSLog(@"Bytes: %d", [receivedData length]);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //TODO error handling for connection
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(apiFailed:)]) {
        [_delegate apiFailed:[error localizedDescription]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Cannot Connect");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [self.receivedData length]);

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [receivedData mutableBytes] length:[receivedData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(apiSucceeded:)])    {
        [_delegate apiSucceeded:jsonString];
    }

}

@end
```

There is no error but it just does not run 'apiSucceeded' method. 
Please dont misunderstand this as a question regarding 'connectionDidFinishLoading'. That bit works well, its the handing of the data BACK to a ViewController that is causing issues.

Can anybody see what I have done wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems that you forgot to set

```
myapi.delegate = self;
```

after

```
Api* myapi = [[Api alloc]init];
```

Comment: @CraigTaub: Note that a better choice for the property name is `delegate` without the underscore (and access it via `self.delegate`). The @synthesize statement and the instance variable is created automatically by the current compiler versions.